# How to add application setup file to visual studio 2010 setup?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have CP210xVCPInstaller_x86.exe software i want add it in my visual studio application.when i an installing my appllication need to instal "CP210xVCPInstaller_x86.exe" this software pls provide the screen shots or steps.
pls give the steps

Comment: How are you creating your setup?  Are you using setup project or WIX or some other method

Comment: If you want a pictorial view, try  http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/231074-setup-and-deployment-in-visual-studio-2010/

Comment: but how can i add external software tomyapplication setup

Comment: cup can u slove my proble pls??

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

1. Open up your setup project
2. Select the **Application Folder**
3. Right click, **Add/File...**
4. Add CP210xVCPInstaller_x86.exe

And that should be it.

**Edit**
To get CP210xVPInstaller_x86.exe to execute, right click on the filename and select the properties window.  In the properties window, set **Condition** to **True**

Comment: @user3445262 What is not working - is the exe not in the installation package?

Comment: project exe is installing but CP210xVCPInstaller_x86.exe file is not installing..

Comment: Did you mean you wanted CP210xVCPInstaller_x86.exe to run as part of the installation

Comment: yes when i am installing my visual studio application setup that time CP210xVCPInstaller_x86.exe file should be install

Comment: I've added an edit to the answer.  May also be worth looking at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/335516/Custom-Action-in-Visual-Studio-setup-projects